# Export data from DB2 to Prometheus using query-exporter

Tags: python-3.x, db2

I am following this article to achieve my goal (to export DB2 Metrics into Prometheus with the help of query-exporter) :

https://pypi.org/project/query-exporter/

I am getting following error while running query-exporter on a linux machine having DB2 as a Database.

```
[root@jupiter-vm792 ~]# query-exporter config.yaml
2019-06-17 06:36:04,814 - ERROR - query-exporter - error from database "db1": '\x02'
2019-06-17 06:36:04,824 - ERROR - query-exporter - error from database "db2": '\x02'
2019-06-17 06:36:04,857 - ERROR - query-exporter - error from database "db2": '\x02'
^C[root@jupiter-vm792 ~]#

I searched for this error online and came across following. 

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n30073.html

which talks about '\x02' but I didn't get.
```

This is what my config.yml file looks like.

config.yml

```
databases:
  db1:
    dsn: ibm_db_sa://db2inst1:passw0rd@x.x.x.x:50000/<DB_NAME>
  db2:
    dsn: ibm_db_sa://db2inst1:passw0rd@x.x.x.x:50000/<DB_NAME>
    keep-connected: true
metrics:
  metric1:
    type: gauge
    description: A sample gauge
  metric2:
    type: summary
    description: A sample summary
    labels: [l1, l2]
  metric3:
    type: histogram
    description: A sample histogram
    buckets: [10, 20, 50, 100, 1000]
queries:
  query1:
    interval: 5
    databases: [db2]
    metrics: [metric1]
        sql: SELECT * FROM HEALTHMETRICS.ALERT_CONFIG_PARAM
```

Comment: Have you verified that a test program can connect to these databases with ibm_sb_sa ? Presumably you have *real* database names instead of placeholders.

Comment: @mao : Yes, I wrote a sample python program and it was able to connect to the database.

Comment: In your test program, are you using ibm_db_sa with the *same connection string as in the config.yml  (assuming you replace the placeholder with a real database name)?   Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Your doc link is to Db2 for z/OS, but it seems you are connecting to Db2 for LUW. Are there any other error messages, anything you see in a log?

Comment: I don't see any log folder inside '/opt/.../db2/V11.1' directory.  Where i can see the logs ?